# MySQL: Get an "array" or "object" from a query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, left-join

I'm writing a small ticketing-system for my php-project and I would like to get all attachments that given for a specific message-id.

*This is my query so far:*

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.from, a.to, a.date, 
       a.title,
       a.content,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tma.filename, tma.filepath) 
FROM bestia_messages AS a 
LEFT JOIN bestia_messages_attachments as tma 
       ON a.id = tma.messageid 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

*My return looks like this:*

```
object(stdClass)#375 (8) { 
    ["id"]       => string(3) "725" 
    ["ticketid"] => string(11) "123456 
    ["from"]     => string(16) "test@example.com" 
    ["to"]=> string(27) "test2@example.com" 
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-08-03 14:47:27" 
    ["title"]=> string(17) "Ticket mit Anhang" 
    ["content"]=> string(775) "Ticket mit Anhang…"
    ["GROUP_CONCAT(tma.filename, tma.filepath)"] => string(212) "Test.pngasdaadasasgsdafasdasdasgasfasf,Bildschirmfoto 2015-07-14 um 17.10.43.png52d0833774bc94698e4101c021deebecf5724a4c65d1efc477948180c072c61778b6c0174040cdef6d94d8669251f0a6646c5caf6e1966b9796625979973b2a4.png" }
```

*So far, so good*

```
`Test.png` is attached to file path `asdaadasasgsdafasdasdasgasfasf`
 and `Bildschirmfoto 2015-07-14 um 17.10.43.png` is attached to file path `52d0833774bc94698e4101c021deebecf5724a4c65d1efc477948180c072c61778b6c0174040cdef6d94d8669251f0a6646c5caf6e1966b9796625979973b2a4.png`.
```

*Now I would like to create an array out of this, so that I could work in PHP like this:*

```
foreach($mesage->attachment as $attachment)
{
    echo 'Filename: '.$attachment->filename;
    echo 'Filepath: '.$attachment->filepath;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: By using a PHP framework ? or an ORM library.

Comment: I'm already using a framework (Joomla).

I'd like to know how to separate the results of my query so that I access them like shown in my example.

Comment: You have clean structured data as starting point: don't ruin that packing it all into a string (and it's not as if you couldn't have a comma in a file name). Using GROUP_CONCAT to reduce bandwidth or whatever is a particularly pointless micro-optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the PHP MySQL functions, they will return an array for you.

Here's an example from W3schools (though I hate recommending anything from them).

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Run SQL query
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "ID: " . $row["id"];
    echo "Name: " . $row["firstname"] . $row["lastname"];
}
$conn->close();
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

If you avoid the `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, your results will be in array form already.

If you absolutely *must* use `GROUP_CONCAT` then you can split your result using...

```
// Convert a long string (separated by commas) into an array
$attachments = explode(',', $attachments);
```

Comment: Hi there and thank you for your answer,

well, maybe I did not make clear what I want ;-)

The query already returns an object with all data like `.id, a.from, a.to, a.date, a.title, a.content`. 

The attachments should be a "subarray" or something like that from this object.

Comment: @MyFault Ok does the last part of my answer help at all? Do you want me to expand on that?

Comment: Hi Simon,

the last part helps.. I expended my initial question so you can see my returning object. I would like to have the "link" between filename and file path somehow. If you could explain that - that would be great :)